# What kind of collection should I use in this case?

Tags: java, list, loops, collections, set

In this use case, I need to store a group of items in a collection `x`. I don't want to insert an item into `x` if it already exists (no duplicates). I also don't care about the insertion order. The size `x` varies greatly (can be very small at <10 items or reach up to the ten-thousands).

Although no duplicates and no order points to using a `Set`, I need to iterate efficiently and quickly over all the items once I've constructed `x` and perform operations using them (but without changing them). Would `Set` still be the best option?

I would appreciate any direction - is it more expensive to check if a `List` contains the element already before each insert (to avoid duplicates) or to iterate over a `Set`'s members? Any advice on best practices / efficiency and cost would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Search operation will be `O(n)` in the `List` and `O(1)` in `Map`. If you are not concerned about the order of the elements and don't want duplicates then you should go for `Set`. Iterating over `Set` shouldn't be a problem and you can do it using an `Iterator` or enhanced `for` loops.

Comment: I also vote for `Set`, and do not think about performance unless you have **proven** it is a problem in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's massively more expensive to check if a `List` contains the element already.

Iterating over a `Set` is a little slower than iterating over a `List` but not massively so, and only by a constant factor, whereas checking for containment of an element in a `List` costs linear time per element and makes the whole thing quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to quickly check if an item already exists, the HashSet is for sure the best choice, as it internally use HashMap, so every lookup is O(1).
While List for this lookup is very expensive, as it checks all the elements one by one.

And when you need to iterate all element, it makes no difference in using List and Set.

Worth noting that HashSet will use more memory, but 10s of thousands should not pose a problem.

So HashSet is a clear winner for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) since it's add and remove operations runs in `O(1)` (assuming even distribution of the hash codes). It may be less efficient than a `HashSet` for adding/removing elements, but it should have a better iteration performance, if many elements are removed after adding a large number of elements.

Requiring `O(n)` for a lookup is generally something you should avoid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest insert the data into a map to avoid duplicate items and then convert the map into a List.

If you are using Java 8 you can do something like this

```
    List<Object> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(x -> x.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a set to construct x after construction of x u can simply copy the contents to a array or any other type in order to improve time complexity at the cost of space complexity.